# Function param causing cursor to jump on .keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, jquery-ui

I have this function that is suppose to pass data through diff textarea's however, the cursor keeps jumping to the end of the text.

```
function KeepReferencesInSync(referenceInput) {
  $(referenceInput).keyup(function () {
    $("input[name=Reference]").val($(this).val());
  }
)}
```

Comment: Can u please explain a bit?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: The user will "change" reference textarea depending on a radio button they click. The idea is for the textarea to seem as  a single field that carries the data through the different options.

Comment: Seems to work perfectly fine on other browsers. The problem is with Chrome.

Comment: Setting the value of an input field does move the cursor, you have to use the selection API to remember the cursor position and reset it after you modify the input. PLEASE format your code, it's kind of rude to make us clean up after you so we can try to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution.

I needed to record the cursor position and set [setSelectionRange] to make sure the cursor doesn't jump. See below.

```
function KeepReferencesInSync(referenceInput) {
    $(referenceInput).on('keyup', function () {

        //get selection position
        var start = this.selectionStart,
        end = this.selectionEnd;

        $("input[name=Reference]").val($(this).val());

        //set the range
        this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach. It's not state-of-the-art but that works.

```js
// Create a list of zone/input/ele
var zoneList = [$('#zone1'),$('#zone2'),$('#zone3')];

// For each zone
$.each(zoneList, function(index, zoneForEvent){
    // Attach keyup event
    zoneForEvent.on('keyup',function(){
        // Get root zone info who trigger event
        var rootZoneId = this.id;
        var rootZoneValue = this.value;
        // Loop on each zone
        $.each(zoneList, function(index, zoneDestination){
            // If zone destination is not root zone
            if (zoneDestination.id !== rootZoneId) {
                // Copy value of root element
                zoneDestination.val(rootZoneValue);
            }
        });       
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="zone1"></textarea>
<input type="text" id="zone2"></input>
<textarea id="zone3"></textarea>
```